# Make a view to update one element in a list in django

Tags: django, templates, view

I am pretty new to django, I am displaying a list of items in my template and each item has an edit button, when user clicks it, an edit form pops up on the page. I am thinking to do this, on clicking edit, a js function is called that hides the rest of the page and the edit form which was hidden till now is made visible, but my problem is I don't know how should that edit form get information about that item to fill the fields of the form. I can make an edit view that will return a form filled with the information, but how will I call it. Is there any other way except ajax, I tried using ajax, it is not working.

This is my present code, but I dont want to use ajax, please tell me if there is some alternative, if not how can I write this ajax query, I dont know much about django.

views/edit_keyword:

```
def edit_keyword(request, id=None):
if id:
    keywword_to_edit=keyword.objects.get(keyword_id=request.POST['edit_keyword_id'])
    form_edit=KeywordForm(request.POST or None, instance=keywword_to_edit)
    if request.POST and form_edit.is_valid():
        form_edit.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list_keyword'))
    return render('form': form_edit)
}
```

javascript edit_key function

```
 function edit_key(id) {
    el = document.getElementById("edit_key");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
  ell = document.getElementById("main_content");
    ell.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
  document.getElementById("edit_keyword_id").value= id;

  $.ajax({
                 type:"GET",
                 url:"/edit_keywords/",
                 data: { edit_keyword_id: id }
                 success: function(response){
                   //I dont know what I should write here to fill the form in my template with the form returned.
                 }
            });
  }
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have attempted to use so that we may better guide you

Comment: can you start with simple ?

Answer (score 0):

You should render the fields two times, one for display in a div and other as a form which should be hidden. This assumes there are multiple education degrees.

```
{% for education in education_list %}
<div id="div_education{{forloop.counter0}}" class="pr mb30">
    <button class="btn btn-profile profile-edit js_edit_education_btn" data-idx={{forloop.counter0}} data-role="button">Edit</button>
    <div class="row mt-10">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">Institute Name</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" data-role="input" data-editable>{{education.institute}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-10">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">Degree</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" data-role="input" data-editable  data-type="qualification">{{education.degree}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<form id="form_edit_education{{forloop.counter0}}" data-url='{% url "something" idx=forloop.counter0 %}' class="js_form_edit_education" style="display:none;">
    <div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{csrf_token_value}}"></div>
    <div class="row mt-10">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">Institute</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" data-role="input" data-editable=""><input class="pro-input js_institute" type="text" name="institute{{forloop.counter0}}" value="{{education.institute}}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-10">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">Degree</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" data-role="mobile" data-editable=""><input class="pro-input js_degree" type="text" name="degree{{forloop.counter0}}" value="{{education.degree}}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-10 save-event">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-sm-push-3 col-md-push-3">
            <button id="save_edit_education{{forloop.counter0}}" class="btn btn-primary" data-idx="{{forloop.counter0}}" type="submit">Save</button>
            <a id="cancel_edit_education{{forloop.counter0}}" data-idx="{{forloop.counter0}}" class="btn js_cancel_edit_education">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

You can easily list the details using the views. Now once the edit button is pressed, show the form and hide the div. Once the user click saves after the edit, call ajax to update the same in your DB.